# add value at 0 th location in array using groovy

Tags: groovy

I am new to groovy application.

My array is  : `def xyz = [{a:'a'},{b:'b'},{c:'c'}]`

My expected output for xyz should be  : `[{x:'x'},{a:'a'},{b:'b'},{c:'c'}]`

Answer (score 2):

given you have:

```
def xyz = [[a:'a'],[b:'b'],[c:'c']]
```

Then you can do:

```
xyz = [[x:'x']] + xyz
```

So that:

```
assert xyz == [[x:'x'], [a:'a'], [b:'b'], [c:'c']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly your example, but I could run this in groovyConsole

```
def xyz = ['a','b','c']
xyz.add(0, 'x')
println xyz
```

which prints

```
[x, a, b, c]
```